# Unable to access Dialogflow V2 detect Intent C# Webhook

Tags: c#, dialogflow-es

Getting following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The Application Default Credentials
> are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute
> Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file
> defining the credentials...

```
public static int DetectIntentFromTexts(string projectId,
                                        string sessionId,
                                        string text,
                                        string languageCode = "en-US")
        {

            var client = SessionsClient.Create();

            var response = client.DetectIntent(
                session: SessionName.FromProjectSession(projectId, sessionId),
                queryInput: new QueryInput()
                {
                    Text = new TextInput()
                    {
                        Text = text,
                        LanguageCode = languageCode
                    }
                });

            var queryResult = response.QueryResult;

            Console.WriteLine($"Query text: {queryResult.QueryText}");
            if (queryResult.Intent != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Intent detected: {queryResult.Intent.DisplayName}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Intent confidence: {queryResult.IntentDetectionConfidence}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Fulfillment text: {queryResult.FulfillmentText}");
            Console.WriteLine();

            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the Credentials.json key generated from Google cloud in your code and set it to the environment variable in the start up of your project.

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", file);
```

//In Global.asax.cs in case of .net framework Application
//In startup.cs in case of .net core Application
//In the above code line **file** means the local path of your credentails.json key